# How can I download the offline installer for ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I am not able to install ASP.NET 5 RC from the following link as the download keeps on breaking due to breaking connection. Is there a way to download all installable files offline so that I can install it on multiple machines as well?

https://get.asp.net/OtherDownloads

Comment: Try this article : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aspnet-5-rc-1-update-offline-installer-ali-bahraminezhad?trk=pulse_spock-articles

Comment: This also may help: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959

Comment: For RC2 offline isntaller try this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-rc2-sdk-preview-1-offline-installer-ali-bahraminezhad

Answer (score 2):

Download [RC2 Preview Installer](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe)

Open a command prompt to the install directory and run `DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe /Layout .\Setup` to download all the installer files to a folder in the current directory called "Setup".

Copy those setup files over to the internetless computer.

Adapted from [hard to understand blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-rc2-sdk-preview-1-offline-installer-ali-bahraminezhad)

Answer (score 1):

Since this version is not officially a 1.0 release, I don't think we're going to see an offline installer just yet.

Also, this version of .NET depends **heavily** on Nuget.org and an internet connection. If your organisation can't open up access to Microsoft-owned websites... you'll have a lot of problems upgrading packages and just plain installing Javascript libraries.

You'll need access to asp.net, microsoft.com, nuget.org, github.com, npm... The offline installer for me is the least of your problem.

Comment: Actually you only need access to nuget and the package feeds that you might use. If you use other package managers like npm you also need access to its repositories. However, you don't need access to "asp.net" or "microsoft.com"

Comment: Does the 600k installer only pull from Nuget?

Comment: Try this article : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aspnet-5-rc-1-update-offline-installer-ali-bahraminezhad?trk=pulse_spock-articles

Comment: Yeah... he will get the ASP.NET installer and be able to install it. Then he'll need access to Nuget.org for packages, npm for javascript packages, bower/github for libraries...

Comment: The problem isn't the lack of Internet connection access. In fact, downloading installer files of ~870 MB through an online installer is the real problem. This is just failing to pay attention to the poor Internet speed in many countries. I use my expensive low-bandwidth home Internet connection of 64KB/s as a criterion to asses which sites/products/tools really suck (with Google Plus ranked 1st).

Comment: You guys are right about all this package management stuff, but this is not an answer; it's a comment. You can get around lack of internet by compiling on a separate server and copy/paste. It's not that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be blocked from installing the .NET Core Tooling Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 installer due to a temporary bug. To workaround it, run the installer from the commandline with the SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1 argument, as you see in the example below.

DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1